# Why is P value for all my predictor variables is non-significant in the univariate logistic regression model?

Tags: regression, logistic-regression

I have run univariate logistic regression model on 5- categorical predictor variables (cat type, age group, rearing, gender, Breed) and also 4- interaction terms to predict one binary outcome variable (positive or negative for a disease), and I realized the non of them were positive P-values at all although there is obvious differences in category numbers among groups (see attached image)[Image for data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVBJg.jpg). Could you please advise on the reasons of this ?

I have used this code:

1. model creation

```
DC_Cattype<- glm(Results ~ Cat_type, data = data_cat, family = "binomial")
DC_Agegroup <- glm(Results ~ Age_group, data = data_cat, family = "binomial")
DC_Gender <- glm(Results ~ Gender, data = data_cat, family = "binomial")
DC_Breed <- glm(Results ~ Breed, data = data_cat, family = "binomial")
DC_Rearing <- glm(Results ~ Rearing, data = data_cat, family = "binomial")

DC_AgegroupXcattype <- glm(Results ~ Age_group * Cat_type, data = data_cat, family = "binomial")
DC_GenderXcattype <- glm(Results ~ Gender * Cat_type, data = data_cat, family = "binomial")
DC_BreedXcattype <- glm(Results ~ Breed * Cat_type, data = data_cat, family = "binomial")
DC_RearingXcattype <- glm(Results ~ Rearing * Cat_type, data = data_cat, family = "binomial")
```

2. output of the model

```
B_coefficient_DC_Cattype<- coef(DC_Cattype)   # B coefficient 
Odds_ratio_DC_Cattype<- exp(coef(DC_Cattype))   # odds ratio
CI_DC_Cattype<- confint(DC_Cattype)   # CI 
P_value_DC_Cattype<- coef(summary(DC_Cattype))[,4]
```

3. Example of results of this output

```
B_coefficient_DC_Cattype
   (Intercept)    Cat_typePet Cat_typeStray  
     0.5108256      0.3158529      0.4610350 
Odds_ratio_DC_Cattype
   (Intercept)    Cat_typePet Cat_typeStray  
      1.666667       1.371429       1.585714 
CI_DC_Cattype
                    2.5 %   97.5 %
(Intercept)    -0.8941688 2.095110
Cat_typePet    -1.4689794 1.993300
Cat_typeStray  -1.2230366 1.997785
P_value_DC_Cattype
   (Intercept)    Cat_typePet Cat_typeStray  
     0.4842541      0.7132484      0.5618967
```